# Why does the k8s example restricted PodSecurityPolicy not restricting RunAsGroup?

Tags: kubernetes, podsecuritypolicy

The K8s documentation has an example for a restricted PodSecurityPolicy:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#example-policies

It restricts 'supplementalGroups' and 'fsGroup' but not 'runAsGroup'

```
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: 'MustRunAs'
    ranges:
      # Forbid adding the root group.
      - min: 1
        max: 65535
  fsGroup:
    rule: 'MustRunAs'
    ranges:
      # Forbid adding the root group.
      - min: 1
        max: 65535
```

Therefore it allows a container in the securityContext to specify the root group with id 0. Isn't this a problem? Shouldn't the following

```
  runAsGroup:
    rule: 'MustRunAs'
    ranges:
      # Forbid adding the root group.
      - min: 1
        max: 65535
```

be added to a restrictive PodSecruityPolicy?

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the following...be added to a restrictive PodSecruityPolicy?

It's an option to restrict your [primary group](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/), if you don't have it then your primary group will not be restricted. So basically, pods can still run containers as the root `Group: 0`.

`supplementalGroups` means any additional group added to the user besides the primary group (secondary groups). In *nix systems ️ you can have a process run as belonging to a [primary group and a set of limited secondary groups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538130/what-is-the-difference-between-primary-group-and-secondary-group-in-ubuntu).

✌️